# Access to a mobile website only from a QR code?

Tags: php, qr-code

Is it possible to limit access to a mobile website via qr code only?

Comment: You could include a secret code in the URL, but once someone has accessed the site, they can easily share the URL with anyone.

Comment: how about a token that expires every some time interval

Comment: More so for analytical purposes.  I know google does a great job, but google wont tell me if the visit was from the qr code.  If I can limit  visits to the qr code then I can precisely narrow down the number of visitors and say...a specific career fair, where only that QR Code is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be absolute accuracy, but if you use a query string it should narrow down the results For example : index.php?refer=QR. I would just like to state now that I am by no means experienced with PHP, so please don't hit me too hard if I get something wrong ;).

Perhaps you could make it so the QR code redirects to a site and that site generates a key, even something as simple as the date and time. Therefore your query string could be: index.php?refer=QR&c=1215

If the code in the query string doesn't match that of the one currently in use then the person has been linked via direct entry, if it does match then a QR code was used.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is point to a long URL that takes you to a page that sets or creates a cookie that must be set to visit the page.

However, if a user gets hold of the long link they could send it round.

What you could do is a php header to redirect and use htaccess to mask the URL so they don't get the URL.

Answer (score 0):

The redirecting solution given by @Sam should work well but if user manually types `index.php?refer=QR&c=1215` or try to access page from history you may not be able to stop the user.

My solution I, although its bit different, is make an and register it to process the your authority `www.something.com`. so the next time user scan a qr, android will read it and prompt user to open it in app and app can use WebView to open page without showing the actual url.

Android will redirect user to web browser if your app isn't installed, the way to handle would be to check if it contain's a app specific query parameter say `source=app` that will be added by app, if not, it will mean its opening from browser and here you can redirect user to install app from store.

Hope this helps...